# "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" while installing NFS server

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, nfs

I am trying to install an NFS server on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine but everytime it gives me an error like this:

```
david@machineA:~$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nfs-common is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nfs-kernel-server : Depends: nfs-common (= 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3) but 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Below is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
david@machineA:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try running `sudo apt-get update` first (and then install nfs)

Comment: Yeah, the required and provided package versions only differ by one minor Ubuntu patch number. Looks like something what would happen intermittently. The version number is [up to `1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.2` now](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/nfs-kernel-server/1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.2) btw.

Comment: I did that already `sudo apt-get update` first and then tried installing nfs.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Aaahh so how do we fix this issue?

Comment: Try updating at least a 2nd time. If that doesn't/didn't help, download `nfs-common` and `nfs-kernel-server` manually in the latest version for your architecture from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/nfs-utils and install them with `dpkg -i`.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy nfs-kernel-server`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands in this order:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

This will basically force the package cache to be updated, as well as upgrade other system utilities.

A problem you may be having is that you're specifying `nfs-common`, which gets the latest version. IIRC, `apt` will fulfill all dependencies (versions included) automagically, but forcing the install of `nfs-common` installs a too-new version of it.

Comment: Still the same issue after I followed the above steps. :(

Comment: best to file a bug report and let the packager fix the dependencies.